# Recognizing US marriage to French citizen in France

Tags: france, marriage, eu-spouses

My wife, who is a French citizen, and I (a US citizen) married in the US.  We have since moved to France and would like to make sure our marriage is formally recognized in France as well.

As I understand it, all we need is to have the marriage recorded in a *livret de famille*.  And it seems, that for marriages abroad, it is the US Consulate for the jurisdiction in which we got married that would issue our *livret*.

In that case, for us it would be the consulate tied to the embassy in Washington, D.C. but I can't find good information on exactly what they need from us.

Meanwhile, it seems almost simpler for us to just get married again in France, but I'm not so sure that this is actually legal.  For example, it is necessary to sign a "ATTESTATION TENANT LIEU DE CERTIFICAT DE COUTUME ET DE CELIBAT" (http://photos.state.gov/libraries/france/45994/acs/usc_paris-coutume-celibat.pdf) which seems to not allow the case where we are, in fact, married to each other (just in the US).  So it seems one would almost have to lie about our current status, which is also not good.

Should I go through the proper steps with the consulate, or try to get married in France?

Comment: There is no US consulate for the jurisdiction in which you got married. Do you mean the *French* consulate for the jurisdiction in which you got married?  Have you seen http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article876?

Comment: This seems to require quite some paperworks : https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F21614 that you must accomplish to a french consulate where the (foreign) marriage was celebretad.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was the French Consulate in D.C. That was clear from later context.

Comment: It seems to me this is the only way. My real question is just that as it seems simpler to just get remarried in France, I wonder if we can just do that.

Comment: you cannot just get remarried : "Vous ne devez pas être déjà marié, que ce soit au regard de la loi française ou d'une loi étrangère." https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F930